# Custom VBA function returning #NAME?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a VBA function to calculate the weight of a determine the weight of a certain item from its model number by comparing it to the model number of items with known weights. For some reason it is only returning **#NAME?**

Here is the code:

```
Function getWeight(model As String) As Double
Dim weight As Double
weight = -1#

Dim compModel As String
compModel = ""

Dim prevNumMatches As Integer
prevNumMatches = 0

Dim numMatches As Integer
numMatches = 0

Dim i As Integer
Dim p As Integer

Dim samePump As Boolean
Dim sameMotor As Boolean
Dim special As Boolean


For i = 2 To 1000
    compModel = CStr(Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 1).Value)

    For p = 1 To Len(compModel)
        samePump = False
        sameMotor = False
        special = False
        numMatches = 0

        If p = 1 Then
            If Mid(model, p, 1) = Mid(compModel, p, 1) Then
                samePump = True
                numMatches = numMatches + 1
            End If
        ElseIf p = 5 Then
            If Mid(model, p, 1) <> "-" Then
                special = True
            End If
            If Mid(model, p, 1) = Mid(compModel, p, 1) Then
                numMatches = numMatches + 1
            End If
        ElseIf p = 9 Then
            If Mid(model, p, 1) = Mid(compModel, p, 1) Then
                sameMotor = True
                numMatches = numMatches + 1
            End If
        Else
            If Mid(model, p, 1) = Mid(compModel, p, 1) Then
                numMatches = numMatches + 1
            End If
        End If

        If samePump And (sameMotor Or special) Then
            If numMatches > prevNumMatches Then
                weight = CDbl(Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 2).Value)
                prevNumMatches = numMatches
            ElseIf numMatches = prevNumMatches Then
                If CDbl(Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 2).Value) > weight Then
                    weight = CDbl(Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 2).Value)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next p
Next i

If weight = -1# Then
    getWeight = 0#
Else
    getWeight = weight
End If
End Function
```

Why is this not returning a number as I expect?

Comment: Have you debugged? Set breakpoint and step through code. Are variables populated with expected values? I have never seen # used like that (-1#, 0#). What is it for?

Comment: I believe #Name means you have a syntax error; you need to check the output formula for spelling, etc.

Comment: Whenever I tried to initialize the double with a decimal of ".0" it would correct it to "#" so -1.0 was auto-corrected to -1#.

Comment: It is not letting me debug, so a syntax error as @Cyril suggested would make sense. Excel is saying it is an Invalid Name Error, but I can't figure out why. In cell B2 I used "=getWeight(A2)". The value in A2 is "R221-FT-AA1". Why would I get an invalid name error here?

Comment: The NAME error suggests the formula name is not recognised. You can step into a function by adding a `Stop` statement at the top.

Comment: You put the function in the worksheet module as opposed to regular module, didn't you?

Comment: Where is this code written in? Macros and UDF's **must** be implemented in **standard modules** (.bas), not classes (i.e. not in documents/worksheets/workbooks, userforms and class modules).

Answer (score 2):

Each iteration of the

```
p = 1 to len(compmodel)
```

loop resets all your Booleans to false.  This means the statement

```
If samePump And (sameMotor Or special) Then
```

is never true because it never evaluates all of those on the same pass of the loop.  Put the boolean setters before the start of the loop instead of in it.

```
samePump = False
sameMotor = False
special = False
numMatches = 0
For p = 1 To Len(compModel)
```

Also if you did want to use the debugger just run this.  That way you can step through the code line by line and see whats going on.

```
Sub main()
Dim THingy As Double
THingy = getWeight("R221-FT-AA1")
MsgBox (THingy)
End Sub
```

Comment: None of that will result in a `#NAME?` error though.

Comment: Aside from that it has to be a problem with the data.  When I plugged this code in it returned 0.  Now it returns a weight.  Have a lookup sheet called weights, ColA is product, ColB is weights.  A2 has product.

Comment: Mat's Mug probably has the #Name answer below.  I just threw this into a module straight away, didn't even think about it.

Comment: You're right about the booleans. I didn't notice that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function is (implicitly) `Public`, so the only way to get a `#NAME?` error is to implement it in the wrong type of module, such that Excel doesn't know what `=getWeight` is referring to.

You need to add a *standard procedural module (.bas)* to your project, cut the function, and paste it in there.

[Bugs aside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43378791/1188513), you should be able to call your UDF from the worksheet.

`ThisWorkbook`, as well as all `Worksheet` modules, `UserForm` modules, and plain class modules, are *blueprints* for **objects**, which means in order to call their public members you need to qualify the member calls with an *instance* of that class... and a UDF (or macro for that matter) call can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Even though the file was saved as a macro enabled workbook (.xlsm) macros were not enabled. When I reopened it this morning, it gave me the option to enable macros. Once I did that and corrected the code as Jared suggested, it all worked as planned.